# Unparented Window cant have HMENU id set?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a custom window class (that I created with `RegisterClassEx()`). If I create a window instance of this class and set its `HMENU` property the `CreateWindowEx()` function fails.

Why can I not set this kind of window's id/`HMENU` id?

```
// hwnd = NULL
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, WND_CLASS_NAME.c_str(), wndTitle.c_str(), wndFlags,    
    wndDimensions.left, wndDimensions.top, wndDimensions.right, wndDimensions.bottom, 
    NULL, (HMENU)50001, hinstance, NULL);

// hwnd is valid
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, WND_CLASS_NAME.c_str(), wndTitle.c_str(), wndFlags,    
    wndDimensions.left, wndDimensions.top, wndDimensions.right, wndDimensions.bottom, 
    NULL, 0, hinstance, NULL);
```

The whole purpose is to be able to call `GetDlgCtrlId(hwnd);`.

Comment: What makes you think 50001 is a valid menu handle?

Comment: @immibis What would be a valid menu value range?

Comment: How about handle returned by `CreateMenu`? You don't use `(HWND)50001` as a window handle, why would you use `(HMENU)50001` as a menu handle?

Comment: Its very common to declare `#define IDM_MYCONTROL 50001` in winapi tutorials (to be passed as the HMENU parameter. Very rarely do they use CreateMenu. This is why I am doing the same.

Comment: Non-child windows by definition cannot have a "child-window identifier" set on them. If your window is not a child window, that parameter becomes a handle to the menu to use for that window's menubar. Sorry. Maybe `GWLP_ID`? Nothing in the documentation says anything about that being invalid for a non-child window, but I'm not sure...

Comment: @Sam The documentation does say that for a top-level window, it's a menu handle, and for a child window it can be a number cast to HMENU (I don't know why they decided to make those two completely separate things use the same parameter). Is this a child window?

Comment: (Also, my original comment was assuming that Microsoft were sane, and that the HMENU parameter had to be a menu handle - which I now see is only true for top-level windows)

Comment: Also why do you want to reference toplevel windows by ID anyway? To store in some sort of `std::map` object? You can store the HWND directly as the key type for that...

Comment: Top-level windows don't have IDs, they use that parameter to define a menu. If you want to set a menu from your resources, you need to use `LoadMenu()` to obtain a handle.

Comment: @immibis: A window is either a child window, or not. A child window is a window with the `WS_CHILD` window style. A child window can have a window ID, but no menu. A non-child window cannot have a window ID, but a menu. This parameter (and the space occupied by the member of the `WND` structure) have mutually exclusive semantics. If you take a look at the minimum hardware specs for Win16 you'll understand, why saving 16 bits usually won when contrasted with marginally cleaner code.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot work. The `CreateWindowEx` function is a little bit confusing in that the interpretation of the parameters differs, depending on which type of window you are creating. You have to read the documentation carefully to avoid making erroneous assumptions.

There are [two fundamental types of windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632597.aspx): **overlapped/pop-up windows** (I think there used to be a distinction back in 16-bit Windows, but that distinction is no longer relevant; these are practically identical) and **child windows**. The first type are the ones you intuitively think of, since they're the ones that *look* like windows. They're what an application uses for its main window, dialog boxes, floating tool windows, etc. The second type are a specific type of windows that can *only* be used as children of another window. Controls are child windows—things like buttons, static controls, listviews, etc. Child windows are hosted by a parent window (they always have a parent), which can either be another child window or an overlapped/pop-up window.

**Only child windows have application-defined IDs.** You specify this ID when calling the `CreateWindowEx` function with the `WS_CHILD` style flag (which requests the creation of a child window). When that flag is present, the `hMenu` parameter is not interpreted as a handle to a menu. Rather, it is interpreted as the child window's ID.<sup>†</sup>

When calling the `CreateWindowEx` function *without* the `WS_CHILD` style flag (which means you are passing either `WS_OVERLAPPED` or `WS_POPUP`, which we have already seen are essentially interchangeable), the `hMenu` parameter is interpreted as a handle to a menu. If it is a valid handle to a menu, then this menu is associated with the window. If it is NULL, then the window uses the class menu (the one specified when `RegisterClassEx` was called during creation of the window class).<sup>‡</sup>

[The function's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx) tries to make this clear in the description of the `hMenu` parameter.
It says:

> *hMenu* [in, optional]
>        Type: `HMENU`
>
> A handle to a menu, or specifies a child-window identifier, depending on the window style. For an overlapped or pop-up window, *hMenu* identifies the menu to be used with the window; it can be NULL if the class menu is to be used. For a child window, *hMenu* specifies the child-window identifier, an integer value used by a dialog box control to notify its parent about events. The application determines the child-window identifier; it must be unique for all child windows with the same parent window.

The implication should be obvious. **A window cannot have both a menu and an ID. It has *either* a menu (if it is an overlapped/pop-up window) *or* a child-window ID (if it is a child window).** Child windows never have menus—this is technically impossible because they have IDs. So what you are trying to do is impossible: overlapped/pop-up windows cannot have an ID set.

You state in the question that your intent is to be able to call the `GetDlgCtrlID` function, but [that function's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645478.aspx) is pretty clear about the fact that it works only for child windows. For starters, the very name of the function implies that it works for *controls* (abbreviated to "ctrl"), which by definition must be child windows. Reading further (italicized annotations are mine):

> GetDlgCtrlID accepts child window handles as well as handles of controls in dialog boxes. *[Technically, this is an unnecessary distinction. As we have seen, controls in dialog boxes* are *child windows. But, presumably, the author was taking special care to be as clear as possible.]* An application sets the identifier for a child window when it creates the window by assigning the identifier value to the hmenu parameter when calling the `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx` function.
>
> Although `GetDlgCtrlID` may return a value if *hwndCtl* is a handle to a top-level window, top-level windows *[by this is meant either overlapped or pop-up windows]* cannot have identifiers and such a return value is never valid.

Note in particular that final sentence.

Of course, there *is* some way to identify overlapped and pop-up windows: their handle. This is the value returned to you by the `CreateWindowEx` function (assuming it is successful), and you can save this handle as the window's ID. It is guaranteed to be unique system-wide (although it may be reused for another window after your window has been destroyed), and is the most reliable way of identifying a window.

If, for some reason, you are unable to save the window handle but still need to find a top-level window later, you can call the [`FindWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499.aspx) function. This uses the window class name and the window caption to find a matching window. If it finds a match, it returns the window handle. (Note again the distinction between top-level and child windows. `FindWindow` does not work on child windows. If you want to search child windows, you must call [`FindWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500.aspx) instead.)

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> Note that, once a child window has been created, its ID can be set or retrieved by passing the `GWL_ID` index to the [`GetWindowLongPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585.aspx) or [`SetWindowLongPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) functions, respectively. This index only has meaning for child windows, because no other type of window has an ID.</sup>

<sup><sup>‡</sup> Note that, once an overlapped/pop-up window has been created, its menu handle can be retrieved with [`GetMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647640.aspx) or set with [`SetMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647995.aspx). Again, the documentation for those functions is forced to emphasize the fact that child windows cannot have menus. `GetMenu` fails when called on a child window, returning an "undefined" result; `SetMenu` similarly fails, setting an error code.</sup>